# BigQuery Results directly in GCS - PHP API

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to export directly the results of a BigQuery Query directly to GCS to avoid storing the query result on my Apache Server and then sending it to GCS (which doesn't work with big files).

**Is there a way to configure the QueryJob to send the data directly to a GCS bucket ?**

Using the PHP API for Google Cloud https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of October 2020 it is possible now with introduction of [EXPORT DATA statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement)

So, now it is as simple as below example

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://bucket/folder/*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY field1 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by combining a Query and Extract job:

```
<?php

use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

$bigquery = new BigQueryClient();

$datasetId = "my-dataset";
$tableId = "my-new-table";
$gsUri = "gs://my-bucket/my-object";

$queryString = "SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_request` LIMIT 1000";

$newTable = $bigquery->dataset($datasetId)
    ->table($tableId);

$q = $bigquery->query($queryString);
$q->destinationTable($newTable);

$bigquery->runQuery($q)
    ->waitUntilComplete();

$extract = $newTable->extract($gsUri);

$newTable->runJob($extract);

$newTable->delete();
```